# insert record into field which should be in between 10000 - 99999 and already not exist in unique_no field records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field name 'unique_no' in a table which contains some records already. 
I want to select records into field 'unique_no' which should be,
 - in between 10000 - 99999 and 
 - already not exist in unique_no field records.

So please suggest me method to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: If ther is UNIQUE index on that field you could use `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` not unique rows won't be inserted

Comment: A check constraint would work well for this.

Comment: may be you mean "insert" rather than "select"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make field `unique_no` as AUTO_INCREMENT.
2. Set table option AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
3. Insert new records, specify NULL for `unique_no` field.

Answer (score 0):

It should be optimized, but basically you need code like (pseudocode):

```
// lock table to prevent duplicates
mysql_lock_table('table');
do {
    $random = rand(10000, 99999);
} while ( mysql_count_rows("SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE unique_no = %value", $random) > 0 );
$row['unique_no'] = $random;
mysql_insert($row);
// unlock table
mysql_unlock_table('table');
```

if table has key UNIQUE on field, you can use `INSERT IGNORE` with affected rows value

```
// lock table to prevent duplicates
do {
    $random = rand(10000, 99999);
    $row['random'] = $random;
    $result = mysql_insert_ignore($row);
} while ( mysql_affected_rows($result) == 0 );
```

Comment: code written on pseudocode, because I not sure how you using mysql in php